# API request to MVC Web API fetting a 400 Bad Request response

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong with this GET request to my API (from Fiddler):

```
http://localhost:51488/api/searchapi/Demo&Dte=2012-08-25&Nts=1
```

It returns a 400 Bad Request HTTP response.

My route is:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

My **SearchAPIController.cs** is:

```
   // GET api/searchapi
    public IEnumerable<RatesViewModel> Get(string id, DateTime Dte, int Nts)
    {
```

So I would expect:

```
id = "Demo"
Dte = 2012-08-25
Nts = 1
```

But it just doesn't appear to get as far as the controller.

Thanks for any help,

Mark

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
http://localhost:41645/api/searchapi/Demo&Dte=2012-08-25&Nts=1
```

should be:

```
http://localhost:41645/api/searchapi/Demo?Dte=2012-08-25&Nts=1
```

Notice that query string parameters start with a question mark (`?`).

Comment: Hi Darin - once again your helping me... thank you very much - will accept as answer when SO allows.  Mark